# Redirecting HTTPS from Elastic Load Balancer to Backend Server

Tags: spring-boot, https, amazon-elb, apigee

I want to forward all the HTTPS request sent to my ELB to my backend servers.
Is it possible that the ELB Load does not decrypt HTTPS requests before routing them to backend servers and leave the decryption process to be a responsibility of my backend server?, so I would not need to create an HTTPS listener?. I am using another proxy layer  (Apigee) between the client and the ELB which provides an abstraction or facade for my backend service APIs and provides security, rate limiting, quotas, analytics, and already encrypted traffic is sent from it to the ELB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up an AWS ELB to be a plain TCP pass-through, so that your Apigee layer will handle the HTTPS handshake and decryption.

> ```
> option_settings:
>   aws:elb:listener:443:
>     ListenerProtocol: TCP
>     InstancePort: 443
>     InstanceProtocol: TCP
> ```

from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-tcp-passthrough.html

Comment: Thanks @evansche. The only issue is that i am using ECS and Fargate. I am not using Beanstalk, so i am not sure what type of ELB i should use in that case.